# installing a replacement ceiling light fixture

Tags: wiring

I am replacing an old light fixture in 1 of my rooms, something I've done before at my other house with no issues but this house is ancient. I took the old one out and there is no box I can see just the metal bar across (I am probably calling it something wrong, don't worry I am posting pictures). There are also only 2 wires available when I am used to the 3 wires but I've read enough to know that's not that big of a problem. the big problem is that both wires are white or are faded white because so old.

Any help in figuring out what wire is what, I would appreciate it. the new light fixture has a white and black cable and a bare copper cable.

[image]

Comment: One piece of good news is that lights don't care which wire is connected.  It is more for your safety and not touch hot when changing light bulbs.  Is there any wood close to that circle you could mount a box to?

Comment: The metal strap across there is for mounting the type of fixture that uses a nipple (threaded tube) for mounting.  Wires could be white because the painter was sloppy; get a tool and see if any paint scrapes off.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do have a box there. It just has the edges covered with a lot of plaster. The pic does show what looks like a partial curving edge to the left of the mounting bar.  That bar also has to be screwed into something.